# from google.cloud.logging_v2 import types ImportError: cannot import name types

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

I'm working on a small app running on GAE. When I deploy my application or try and use virtualenv (per the docs), I see the following in the logs in Cloud Platform (they're the same locally, too) when I try and access the app:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/d~my-project/gen-debug:413039252702584887/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.cloud import logging_v2
File "/base/data/home/apps/d~my-project/gen-debug:413039252702584887/lib/google/cloud/logging_v2/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.logging_v2 import types
ImportError: cannot import name types
```

My code that's throwing this error looks like this:

```
from google.cloud import logging_v2
client = logging_v2.LoggingServiceV2Client()
c = client.list_log_entries(["my-project"], filter_='resource.type="global" AND jsonPayload.hello="there"')
l = list(c)
l1 = l[0]
desc, value = l1.ListFields()[1]
print desc.camelcase_name, dict(value.items())
```

The thing that is so freaking weird is that in Google, I can go into a Cloud Shell session, get into ipython, and this code totally works.

```
me@cloudshell:~ (my-project)$ ipython2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 5.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from google.cloud import logging_v2
...: client = logging_v2.LoggingServiceV2Client()
...: c = client.list_log_entries(["my-project"], filter_='resource.type="global" AND jsonPayload.hello="there"')
...: l = list(c)
...: l1 = l[0]
...: desc, value = l1.ListFields()[1]
...: print desc.camelcase_name, dict(value.items())
...: 
jsonPayload {u'hello': u'there'}
```

What's going on that makes running this on GAE different than running it in the Google Cloud Shell? This import error seems like a Google issue, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the generic [python client for Stackdriver logging](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/index.html). Which isn't designed for/supported on GAE first-generation (i.e., Python 2.7) apps as this runtime already has it's own (customized) stackdriver logging integrated.

From [Supported environments](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/#environments):

> The following VM instances support Stackdriver Logging using their own
>   software, possibly including custom versions or configurations of the
>   Stackdriver Logging agent. Manually installing the Stackdriver Logging
>   agent on them is not supported:
>
> - [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) standard environment VM instances. App Engine includes built-in support for Stackdriver Logging. For more
>     information, see [Stackdriver Logging in App Engine Apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging).
> - [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) flexible environment VM instances. Apps running in the App Engine flexible environment can write logs that are in
>     addition to what is included in the App Engine standard environment.
>     For more information, see [Stackdriver Logging and the App Engine
>     flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging/#stackdriver_logging_and_the_flexible_environment).